# mysql GROUP BY doesn't match DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, distinct

I must be missing an obvious thing since after hours of testing I seem to be blind

table 1 created with

```
CREATE table1
SELECT column1,column2,SUM(column3) 
FROM table2 
WHERE condition1 
GROUP BY column1,column2
```

doesn't have the expected row count

So I wanted to check table2 with

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column1,column2) FROM table2 WHERE condition1
```

and that gave me the expected row count

What is wrong in my way of proceeding ?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @RaymondNijland removed. I misread it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers would be different if either `column1` or `column2` were `NULL`.

`count(distinct)` does not count `null` values.  When used with multiple arguments, this is true even when only one expression is `null`.

However, `null` values go on separate rows in a `group by`.